# How to correctly send a ResultReceiver subclass to a Service?

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to bind to a custom service with no success.

**My custom service**

```
public class CustomService extends Service {
    private CustomReceiver mReceiver;
    private final CustomBinder mBinder = new CustomBinder();

    public class CustomBinder extends Binder implements ICustomService {
        // Implementation of the interface
    }

    public interface ICustomService {
        // Public interface to comunicate to the service
    }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("customservice", "Service bound.");
    mReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver"); // ERROR HERE!
    return mBinder;
}

// Other methods
```

**My custom receiver**

```
public class CustomReceiver extends ResultReceiver {    
    public interface IReceiver {
        public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData);
    }

    private IReceiver mReceiver;

    public CustomReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    public void setReceiver(IReceiver receiver) {
        mReceiver = receiver;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        if (mReceiver != null) {
            mReceiver.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        }
    }
}
```

**My activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CustomReceiver.IReceiver {
    IRegressiveService mService;
    CustomReceiver mReceiver;
    boolean mBound = false;

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mService = (ICustomService) service;
            mBound = true;
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        mReceiver = new CustomReceiver(new Handler());
        mReceiver.setReceiver(this);

        Intent bindServiceIntent = new Intent(this, CustomService.class);
        bindServiceIntent.putExtra("receiver", mReceiver);
        bindService(bindServiceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

**Stacktrace (incomplete)**

```
04-29 20:23:55.851: E/AndroidRuntime(690): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 20:23:55.851: E/AndroidRuntime(690): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind to service [package].CustomService@44f38cd8 with Intent { cmp=[package].CustomService (has extras) }: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.ResultReceiver
04-29 20:23:55.851: E/AndroidRuntime(690): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService(ActivityThread.java:2996)
[...]
04-29 20:23:55.851: E/AndroidRuntime(690): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.ResultReceiver
04-29 20:23:55.851: E/AndroidRuntime(690): at [package].CustomService.onBind(CustomService.java:37)
04-29 20:23:55.851: E/AndroidRuntime(690): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService(ActivityThread.java:2983)
[...]
```

**In short**

In the Activity, I pass to the Service a instance of `CustomReceiver` (a `ResultReceiver` subclass) with the "receiver" key. But when I try to recover this object, in the Service, `ClassCastException` is raised. Why? How can I fix this?

I am targeting API level 8.

And I can not find this behavior in any of other SO questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just checked my code. Try declaring `mReceiver` in your `Service` as a base `ResultReceiver` as follows...

```
public class CustomService extends Service {
    private ResultReceiver mReceiver;
    ...
}
```

This is what I do and I don't get a `ClassCastException` in my `Service` when getting the receiver from the `Intent` (mine is also a custom `ResultReceiver`).

Comment: @borges - How do you send callback? onReceiveResult() method is protected and can't be called directly from CustomReceiver class.

Comment: But if you do that, dont u lose the actual CustomReciever object as it now strips it out and uses base ResulReciever?

Comment: @jonney : Yes and no. The only useful thing you can do with a class which extends `ResultReceiver` is to use its `send(...)` method. Any customization should inevitably done with the overridden `onReceiveResult(...)` method (the base method does nothing). In short, the instance of the `ResultReceiver` which is retrieved by the `Service` can only be used to 'send' a result back and any other customizations can only be used by the extended `ResultReceiver` itself and not by the `Service`.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same issue with the `ClassCastException` and it did not make any sense to me. I saw the answer here about setting the `mReceiver` to just use a `ResultReceiver` instead of the `CustomReceiver` in the Service. I did that and still got the same error, but I noticed that my `import` Statements were not the same.

In my MainActivity I imported the statement:

```
import android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver;
```

However in my service I had imported the statement:

```
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
```

I made sure in my service and my MainActivity I used following:

```
import android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver;
```

It now works properly! Hope this helps someone!

I'm also a few years late..

Answer (score -1):

A `BroadcastReceiver` is (by default) not `Parcelable`. So you'll expect to get a ClassCastException. If you need to pass a specific instance add a setter method to your Service and then call that method from your ServiceConnection implementation with the object.

Comment: Your solution seems to work (although I could not test yet). But I'm inheriting `ResultReceiver` (which according to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html) is parcelable) and not `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @borges: Just to confirm - yes you can pass a `ResultReceiver` as a parcelable extra in an `Intent` - I do it myself. Not sure what the answer to your question is though.